# Preventing NuGet package update in team environment

Tags: validation, nuget, shared-libraries, nuget-package, package-management

We have a large solution with many projects, and many developers working together.

We need a way to validate Nuget package versions to insure no developer accidentally breaks the build with a package update.

Ideally, is there a way to validate and interupt/stop during Nuget package installation if it is a known incompatible package? We know we can do a validation at build time, but Ideally I'd like to actually be able to stop/inform the developer the newer version is not supported in the build to prevent them from going off and building with the newer package, only at build time to discover they've wasted time on a new package that might have differing calls etc.

If this is not possible, what would be the easiest way to do this at build time? I'm thinking a pre-build script but interested in other ideas. Effectively, the script would look across other project package versions to compare and inform if an incorrect version (and stop a publish to a shared location during build).

Comment: If you're using `PackageReference`, you can try doing something like https://github.com/davkean/maket. So even if a developer changes the version, the version will be updated by the targets to the pinned version.

Comment: This is currently not possible, but there are request similar your scenario. 
There is a spec that's being actively worked on.
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6764
 Feel free to add your comments/thoughts on it.

As far as a workaround goes, try Maket or Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions -https://github.com/Microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/master/src/CentralPackageVersions#microsoftbuildcentralpackageversions

Comment: It isn't terribly painful to interrupt everyone and correct the incorrect Nuget package - however, it is more of a disruption to the developer that began working with the incorrect package version. Often object models and syntax change, so this would be really nice for large teams to help manage consistent build process. I've found a work around just with powershell script and xpath to query all package.config files and we'll front this in our gulp and MSBuild scripts at build time for the entire solution, really no other effective way I've been able to determine.